# How CXF Handles APIs If those are not annotated with the @Path Variable?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, cxf

**Scenario-1 : During my work I encountered below scenario, On which : getText1, getText2,getText3,getText4,getText5,getText6 are without @Path annotations,**

But when I call the API (http://localhost:8080/.../testqa/ )it always returns following result :

```
{
    "name" : "Sumit1 Arora",
    "age" : 21,
    "address" : "Lakshay1 Arora"
}
```

**SimpleQAImpl**

```
@Service("qaservice")
@Path("/testqa")
public class SimpleQAImpl {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/simpleqa")
    public Person getText() {
        return new Person("Sumit Arora",21,"Lakshay Arora");
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getText1() {
        return new Person("Sumit1 Arora",21,"Lakshay1 Arora");
    }



    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getText3() {
        return new Person("Sumit3 Arora",21,"Lakshay3 Arora");
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getText4() {
        return new Person("Sumit4 Arora",21,"Lakshay4 Arora");
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getText5() {
        return new Person("Sumit5 Arora",21,"Lakshay5 Arora");
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getText6() {
        return new Person("Sumit6 Arora",21,"Lakshay6 Arora");
    }
}
```

1. May you please tell me how Apache CXF works, if @Path not given like the case above or on other scenarios as well?
2. Is there any reference to understand such stuff?

---

**Scenario-2 : On this scenario, No @Path variable defined on top of API Call, how all of these API would be called from URI ?**

```
@Service
@Path("/customer")
public class CustomerResource {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerResource.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(Customer customer) {

        if(customerService.createCustomer(customer).isPresent()) {
            return Response.ok().build();
        } else
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(new Error(1,"test")).build();
    } 

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAll() {
        logger.debug("Received request to fetch all the customers.");
        List<Customer> customers = customerService.fetchAll();
        GenericEntity<List<Customer>> customerEntities = new GenericEntity<List<Customer>>(customers) {};
        return Response.ok(customerEntities).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response update(Customer customer) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
    } 
}
```

Comment: It goes off the `@Path` on the class. The methods not annotated are considered _root resources_ because they root resource class uri, and methods annotated are considered _sub resources_ as they are sub resources of the root resource

Comment: The first block of code, you should never ever have. In Jersey the application won't even launch. The resource methods are too ambiguous. The way to disambiguate them is the use different producing media types. Other wise if the app _does_ launch, it's up for grabs which one will be picked.

Comment: Remember that URI match to a single resource. So each resource path, unless templated (eg `{id}`) should only lead to one resource, but can produce different content types. So the only variations you should have on the same path, is either from different content types or different HTTP methods. Your resource methods have neither. So you need to change them. The second code snippet is fine, as they have different HTTP methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for how CXF selects which method is executed is here: [CXF resource selection overview](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Overviewoftheselectionalgorithm.). The docs talks about which method it prefers by looking at which has more path parameters or more a more specific path but each method in your first scenario has the same path so the first one is chosen. To differentiate between them you could use a path parameter.

The Second scenario requires you to change the HTTP method used with the URL so:

- POST /customer
- GET /customer
- PUT /customer

would each invoke the different methods.